# how to set visibility options of android.widget.textview

Tags: android, textview, android-studio, visibility

had FC issues with this

```
private TextView msg, NameOut, DateOut;
msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtviewOut) ;
```

down the line... (problem lies here)

```
msg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//set visibility to false on create
```

how do I set the visibility of this TextView (msg) to false when the app starts?

**UPDATE AFTER #1 Answer EDIT**

okay here is all the code:

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textenter"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbledt1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Name"
        android:id="@+id/lbledt1"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter your date of birth (e.g. xx July 19xx)"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textenter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press this button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="You have been awesome since"
        android:id="@+id/txtviewOut"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtoutName"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtviewOut"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtOutDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtviewOut"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

```
MainActivity.java:



 package com.example.helloandroidstudio;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private Button btnClick;
        private EditText Name, Date;
        private TextView msg, NameOut, DateOut;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button) ;
            Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textenter) ;
            Date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText) ;
            msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtviewOut) ;
            NameOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtoutName) ;
            DateOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutDate) ;

    //        msg.setVisibility(View.GONE);//set visibility to false on create
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
        }

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (v == btnClick)
            {
                if (Name.equals("") == false && Date.equals("") == false)
                {
                    NameOut = Name;
                    DateOut = Date;
                    msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    msg.setText("Please complete both fields");
                    msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }

    }
```

I tried it with setInvisibility(View.GONE), but still FC

I check witht the id values, there isa  aid value assisgned and I did do the typecast of the object...

please keep in mind, I have done c#, but this is my first java/android app so please bear with me

Comment: it should work, or you are finding another view with other resId , put the Layout xml code . you can change the visibility to INVISIBLE or GONE to hide the TextView

Comment: Post LogCat Error please.

Comment: Checkout this [android example for TextView setVisibility](http://android.codota.com/scenarios/528e1e7dda0a83c09d43d799/TextView.setVisibility?tag=bumblebee)

Comment: `if (Name.equals("") == false && Date.equals("") == false)` Change to    `if (Name.getText().equals("") == false && Date.getText().equals("") == false)`

Answer (score 13):

well i have some doubt what exactly are you trying to accomplish , but i would try to clear some concept

> if you want to hide your view completely then use Visibility.Gone or if you want to hide it but want to keep the place then use Visibility.Invisible

```
msg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // for hiding but keeping the place of your view 

msg.setVisibility(View.GONE);// for  hiding it completely , view will not take any place
```

Answer (score 4):

Set that as the default in your layout.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtviewOut"
    ...
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

**UPDATE:**

If you always need it to start off invisible, this is the way to go.  Note that "invisible" means that it's not displayed but it will still take up blank space when rendering.  If you want it to be collapsed (does not take up any space, does not display), then use `View.GONE` in code or `android:visibility="gone"` in your layouts.

If calling setVisibility on a View causes a FC, that's most likely going to be a null pointer exception (check in LogCat though to be sure).  If that's the case, you either haven't called findViewById yet or your layout does not contain the view by that id.

**UPDATE #2:**

First of all, you should always look at LogCat and get the exact exception that is thrown and the exact line it is thrown on.  I'm willing to bet it happens on this line:

```
                NameOut = Name;
                DateOut = Date;
```

You're attempting to set a variable of type TextView to a value of type EditText.  What I assume you're trying to do is set the text of your TextView to the value of the text in your EditText.  This is done as follows:

```
NameOut.setText(Name.getText().toString());
DateOut.setText(Date.getText().toString());
```

Comment: later in the program, how would i make it visible again?

Comment: msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   Null check it if you're getting force closes when executing this code.  The only reason this should crash would be that you're accessing it when it's either not in the layout or you haven't resolved it yet.

Comment: okay, i posted all the code, what do u think can cause the error

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented an

```
onClick(View v)
```

method but did not wire up with your Button in the layout.

Set the property `android:onClick="onClick"` in your layout xml file.

Right now, your button click is not getting registered and the method is not getting executed

Answer (score 0):

For Doing this in *Kotlin*:

```
<Text android:visibility="gone"/>
```

If you always need it to start off invisible, this is the way to go. Note that "*invisible*" means that it's not displayed but it will still take up blank space when rendering. If you want it to be collapsed (does not take up any space, does not display), then use `View.GONE` in code.

For Visibility:

```
text.Visibility = View.Visible
```

For Gone :

```
text.Visibility = View.Gone
```

(As Gone does not uses your space in `main_activity.xml`.
It Consumes Space Only When it is Set To Visible.)